# Where I can get complete list of Amazon MWS product categories?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I need to develop application that send feed submissions via amazon mws. But I'm currently in trouble, because when you send new product to amazon you must specify product category. I found list of categories for different endpoints in the [Amazon Marketplace Web Service Products
API Section Reference](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/MWSProductsApiReference._V398148948_.pdf) but I believe this isn't the complete list of categories, because those main categories also have child categories that are not listed.

I searched all over the internet but I'm still stuck. Also looked in the api docs if I can send request to list all available categories but no luck yet. Any help will be welcome guys.

Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I don't think the products api is where you need to look, look in the api for feeds instead.

Comment: I've looked everywhere in the documentation Jim. No luck yet.

Comment: If you are using XML-formatted feeds, see the guide Selling on Amazon Guide to XML for details about the
schemas for the various feed types. For example, page 12 of the guide provides information about the Product
Feed schema. If you need to determine the correct ItemType for a feed, see the Category-Specific XSDs table
in the Seller Central help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a list of product categories ( and the sub categories ) you will need to log into seller central, then help -> Manage inventory -> Reference -> Tree Guides.

Alternatively [here is the link](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html/ref=au_1661_cont_help?ie=UTF8&itemID=1661&language=en_US). Note, you will still need to authenticate for that link to work.

Answer (score 1):

We know Country BTG files contain all categories, such as:
https://d1c723f3ouvz7y.cloudfront.net/US_btg.xlsx

You can now certainty deduct other countries BTG URL...
for example for canada, it would be:

https://d1c723f3ouvz7y.cloudfront.net/CA_btg.xlsx